# nginx and apache servers

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

I have my website built with django running on an apache server and I want to install nginx for static file serving. Do you think there is any considerable difference if i put nginx on port 80 and proxy requests to apache, or leave apache on port 80 and proxy requests to nginx.
Why I ask is because I would rather leave apache on 80 because I have cpanel on my webserver and changing apache port would be more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Create an IP alias on your primary interface, bind httpd to the main address, and bind nginx to the alias address.

Comment: Is there any advantage to doing this? I know I can use nginx as a front-end and I believe I can use apache as front-end also and nginx serving static files on another port and I could just proxy requests from apache to nginx. Another IP address would just cost more.

Comment: The advantage is that you wouldn't have to proxy the requests. Proxying has a non-zero cost itself.

Comment: How can I do this? I mean don't I have to use something la proxy just to the other ip on port 80? Can you please give me a line doing this, so I could understand how you do it?

Comment: Add a second DNS entry (e.g. `static.example.com`) pointing to the alias address, then change the media URL to that name.

Comment: ah, that would Imply I go through all sources and change the domain for everything that is static, like having it on another server

Comment: @Virgil Balibanu - exactly :)